# symfony2 boostrap 3 layout keeping a label for checkbox even if label set to false

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, templating

I am using symfony2 and the built-in twig default bootstrap horizontal layout.

The issue I face is when rendering a checkbox with 'label' => false, there still is a control label in the form and a weird padding.

i've tried to everride the template by adding the following code but then I get two labels when the label is not set to false :

```
{% extends "bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block checkbox_radio_label %}
    {% if required %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if parent_label_class is defined %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ parent_label_class)|trim}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if label is empty %}
        {{ widget|raw }}
    {% else %}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
        {{ widget|raw }}
        {{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
        </label>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock checkbox_radio_label %}

{% block checkbox_widget -%}
    {% set parent_label_class = parent_label_class|default('') %}
    {% if 'checkbox-inline' in parent_label_class %}
        {{ form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) }}
    {% else %}
        {% if label is empty %}
            <div align="center" class="fmu_single_label">
                {{ form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) }}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="checkbox">
                {{ form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

Any idea on how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Arf, found it with

```
{% extends "bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block checkbox_radio_label %}
    {% if required %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if parent_label_class is defined %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ parent_label_class)|trim}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if label is empty %}
        <div align="center" class="fmu_single_label">
        {{ widget|raw }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
        {{ widget|raw }}
        {{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
        </label>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock checkbox_radio_label %}
```

and custom css on fmu_single_label